# WCF - Publisher/Subscriber - Event

Tags: wcf, publish-subscribe

Is it possible to implement a publisher/subscriber model in WCF only by using events (i.e. not Lists or Dictionaries)?

If yes, plz provide me with a web link of an example application, Or any article that talks about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) is an MSDN article all about it.

Comment: Any up-to-date article? That one [is really old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507977/authoritative-up-to-date-tutorial-for-wcf-callback-and-publish-service-mechanism)

Answer (score 2):

Events are not possible in WCF. You have to use [Callback-Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.callbackcontract.aspx). [Here](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/wcf_alarmclock.htm) you can find some information about the Publisher/Subscriber-Pattern in WCF.

Answer (score 2):

I would refer you to Juval Lowy's website, [IDesign.net](http://www.idesign.net.).  He is the author of arguably the definitive book on WCF, [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308).  His website is full of all kinds of examples that are freely available, including a working WCF Publish-Subscribe framework.  Look for the [Publish-Subscribe Framework](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#InstanceManagement) in the Downloads area.